# JavaFx TableView data not visible in Object oriented design

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

Table view data showing(from database) as well when i typed code into the controller. 
but if try as OOP design data come form database but it hidden.
if i clicked on a row then i can see which row i selected by `System.out.println();`

hears my files and code.

> Supplyer.java `//object`

```
public ObservableList<SupplyerList> supplyerDetails = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void view() {
        DBConnection dbCon = new DBConnection();
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pst;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            con = dbCon.geConnection();
            pst = con.prepareCall("select * from Supplyer");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
                supplyerDetails.addAll(new SupplyerList(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2)));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Supplyer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

> SupplyerController.java `ControllerClass`

```
@FXML private TableView<SupplyerList> tblSupplyer;
@FXML private TableColumn<SupplyerList, String> clmSUpplyerId;
@FXML private TableColumn<SupplyerList, String> clmSupplyerName;

public void showDetails() {

        clmSUpplyerId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SupplyerList, String>("supplyerId"));
        clmSUpplyerId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SupplyerList, String>("supplyerName"));
        tblSupplyer.setItems(supplyer.supplyerDetails);

        supplyer.view();
    }
```

> SupplyerList `object for table view`

```
public class SupplyerList {

    private final SimpleStringProperty supplyerId;
    private final SimpleStringProperty supplyerName;



    public String getSupplyerId() {
        return supplyerId.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty supplyerIdProperty() {
        return supplyerId;
    }

    public void setSupplyerId(String supplyerId) {
        this.supplyerId.set(supplyerId);
    }

    public String getSupplyerName() {
        return supplyerName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty supplyerNameProperty() {
        return supplyerName;
    }

    public void setSupplyerName(String supplyerName) {
        this.supplyerName.set(supplyerName);
    }

    public SupplyerList(String supplyerId, String supplyerName) {
        this.supplyerId = new SimpleStringProperty(supplyerId);
        this.supplyerName = new SimpleStringProperty(supplyerName);
    }
```

Comment: You are not setting the cellvalue factory of clmSUpplyerName. Is it typo or cause of your problem?

Comment: OMG how do i do that...
thank you so much